# Linq query to perform a full text search

Tags: linq

How can the following be done with a linq statement?

```
SELECT Description 
FROM Production.ProductDescription 
WHERE FREETEXT(Description, 'Some Keywords')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the full text search function FREETEXT in TSQL is not directly accessible with Linq to SQL.

You would have to execute that query directly in a database function, then you can pull your result set back with Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but you might have to search each column/property of the table against your keyword to mimick freetext. 
ex:

```
    context.Production.ProductDescription
.Where(pd=>pd.Property1.Contains("Keyword") || pd.Property2.Contains("Keyword");
```